# Gorm dynamic ignore field

Tags: go, struct, go-gorm

I would like to ignore fields dynamically. There existing : gorm:"-" or sql:"-" but both are not dynamic. No information in gorm's docs.

```golang
type data struct {
    index int `gorm:"type:int(11);null"`
    id    int `gorm:"type:int(11);null"`
    temp int `gorm:"type:int(11);null"`
}
```

For example, in this case i would like to ignore temp and no pushing it when I'm creating a record. But sometimes I would like to push temp with a simple bool, and the same struct.

```golang
if temp {
//push weather
}else {
//no push weather
}
```

Comment: This means that anycase the **temp** attribute exists in your table because otherwise the push on temp scenario will fail. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, temp exists in db when i choose to push temp informations. But sometimes field temp doesn't exist in db and I don't want to push temp informations. Otherwhile, gorm say Error 1054: Unknown column 'temp' in 'field list'.

Comment: This means that this dynamic behaviour is performed also on the database and this is incompatible with the database schemas base concept. Moreover even if you create the table without  **temp** column, based on your approach, you should alter the table to add that column when you need to push a row with temp information filled. So starting from that moment you'll always have the column on the schema.
If you confirm instead that temp column is always present on the schema I can share a possible solution for this